# Derived column to get date from filenanme not working as expected

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a ssis package with flat file and oledb destination..

i need to get the date from file name and add it as new column in DB

but it is not working

I did this in derived column

`SUBSTRING(@[User::OS_file],27,10)`  but it returns date when tried in sql-server

file name is like this

asjfbdsajfsd_21-08-2001_osss.log

i need `21-08-2001`

how evere trying with `SUBSTRING(@[User::OS_file],27,10)`  results me this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you're using the wrong index in your `SUBSTRING`.  It looks like it's pulling part of the path instead of part of the file name.  What if you do this?

```
SUBSTRING(@[User::OS_file],50,10)
```

Note, I've changed the start index from `27` to `50`.

Comment: ya..i have used wrong index but changing <<start>> in substring it works but the column is not getting added to my DB ? can you pls help !

Comment: +1 ..basically i have a one variable to looop thr subfolders ! to get all file names as above .. can you explain how did changing <<start>> worked ?

Comment: and could you pls tell me how do i create a variable one for looping all subfolders and one for storing the file name !! i am very new to ssis !

Comment: @user3449213 -- Since you had your index at `27`, I just counted the characters in "an2014\SA\" and added that to 27, then I counted the characters in the beginning of "asjfbdsajfsd_21-08-2001_osss.log" up to the point where the date starts, and added that to my earlier result.  That brought the string index up to the point where the date starts.

Comment: As for your other question, that is a different question and you should ask it separately.  I don't know anything about SSIS, unfortunately.  I was just applying general knowledge of string manipulation (e.g. `SUBSTRING`).

Comment: thanks alot ! but that derived column is not getting added to my DB :(